# How do I know that a Virtual Machine in Azure use the Local network gateway route to connect to an on-premise network?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-machine, gateway, azure-virtual-network

Here a Data engineer who needs your help to setup a connection to an on-premise environment :)!

I have created a virtual network (10.0.0.0/16) with a default subnet (10.0.0.0/24).
Then I created a (Windows) virtual machine which is connected to the vnet/subnet and has allowed ICMP inbound and outbound rules for the ping test. Ping google.com is no problem.

The next step was to create a Virtual network gateway & Local network gateway to connect to an on-premise environment.
The Local network gateway has an Site-to-site (IPsec) connection to a VPN device from a third party (over which I have no control). Status in the Azure portal = 'Connected'.

The third party is able to ping the Virtual Machine in Azure, the 'data in' property on the VPN connection shows that 2 kb (ping) has been received. So that works!

When i try to send a ping command to the ip-address (within the 'address space' specified from the Local network gateway) the ping command fails (Request timed out.).

After a lot of searching on google/stackoverflow I found out that I need to configure a Route Table in Azure because of the BGP = disabled setting. So hopefully I did a good job configure the Routing Table Routes but still I can't perform a successful ping :(!

Do you guys/girls know which step/configuration I have forgotten or where I made a mistake?
I would like to understand why I cannot perform a successful ping to the on-premise environment. If you need more information, please let me know

[Site-to-site (IPsec) connection screenshot/config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g32wc.png)

[Routing Table setup screenshot/config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZzDj.png)

[Routing Table Routes in more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt1Ei.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are **NOT** using **BGP** between the Azure VPN gateway and this particular network, you must provide a list of valid address prefixes for the **Address space** in your local network gateway. The address prefixes you specify are the prefixes located on your on-premises network.

In this case, it looks like you have added the address prefixes. Make sure that the ranges you specify here do not overlap with ranges of other networks that you want to connect to. **Azure will route the address range that you specify to the on-premises VPN device IP address**. There are no other operations that we can do. We don't need to set UDR, especially we don't associate a route table to the Gateway Subnet. Also, avoid associating a network security group (NSG) to the Gateway Subnet. You can check the route table by selecting `Effective routes` for a network interface in Azure VM. Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem).

If you would like to verify the connection from Azure VNet to an on-premise network, ensure that you PING a real private IP address from your on-premise network(I mean the IP address is assigned to an on-premise machine), you can check the IP address with `ipconfig/all` in local CMD. Moreover, you could Enable ICMP through the Windows firewall inside the Azure VM with the PowerShell command `New-NetFirewallRule –DisplayName "Allow ICMPv4-In" –Protocol ICMPv4`. Or, instead of using PING, you can use the PowerShell command [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps#example-4--test-a-connection-to-a-remote-host) to test a connection to a remote host.

If the problem persists, you could try to [reset the Azure VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/reset-gateway) and reset the tunnel from the on-premises VPN device. To go further, you could [follow these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-cannot-connect) to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I will look into it!

Comment: If you disassociated your Azure VNet with UDR, can you show the Effective routes for your Azure VM NIC?

Comment: At the moment the Route Table is configured with 2 routes containing the Address prefix corresponding to the Address space specified in the local network gateway. If I understand correctly, this is correct?

[Routing Table Routes in more detail][3]

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt1Ei.png

Comment: According to my understanding, you don't need to add routes in that default and gateway subnet as Azure will add the system route and the default route for Azure virtual network gateway.